# How can I get a session timeout page to bubble up out of an iframe?

Tags: iframe, session-timeout

I've got a web app in asp.net that uses an Infragistics control for making tabs. Each tab is an iframe, which is nice because only the current tab's page is rendered instead of rendering all of the tabs.

However, when a page times out within one of the iframes, only that iframe redirects to the login page instead of the whole window. Is it possible to bubble this up somehow to have the whole site redirect to the login page instead of just the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three answers:

- If your tab iframes point to the same domain+port, you can use inter-frame communication via the `window` object to let the parent frame also reload.
- If your iframes are on different doamins and/or ports, and you **can** modify its contents, you can use the [OpenAjax Hub](http://www.openajax.org/index.php) to transfer messages to your parent domain.
- If your iframes are on different domains and/or ports and you can **not** modify its contents, there is no way to achieve what you want due to browser security.